# I Get "gpg: no valid OpenPGP data found" error while importing google key

Tags: 14.04, upgrade, google, openpgp

Everything was working but suddenly stopped. I just didn't upgrade my Ubuntu 14.04 for two months. Now when I want to upgrade I get some errors.

First I run `sudo apt-get update`:

```
E: GPG error: http://dl.google.com stable InRelease: Clearsigned file isn't valid, got 'NODATA' (does the network require authentication?)
```

I search for a solution and found [this](http://www.google.com/linuxrepositories/), but now when I try to import the key, I get another error. While importing the key:

```
wget -q -O - https://dl-ssl.google.com/linux/linux_signing_key.pub | sudo apt-key add -
```

I get this error:

```
gpg: no valid OpenPGP data found.
```

How to solve this problem?

Comment: What's your GnuPG version? check with `gpg --version`

Comment: @remyseroos gpg (GnuPG) 1.4.16

Comment: Can you see the key if you just go to the url from your browser?

Comment: @remyseroos Oh, No! I can't see it. Thank you man. Solved!

Comment: np, Can you please write out your solution/finding as an answer, and mark it solved?

Comment: I just posted the solution, but I'm not able to mark it as solved in 2 days.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The problem was due to the restriction in my country. As @remyseroos suggested me, I tried to open the URL (https://dl-ssl.google.com/linux/linux_signing_key.pub) in my browser and I found out it's not loading properly.

So I just used a proxy and problem solved!

Comment: My problem too. Which proxy you used?

Comment: @afsharm Any VPN service should work.